# Backspace problems in python-mode

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, python, indentation

I'm having trouble getting the `py-electric-backspace` command to execute when I hit backspace at the end of a line of only spaces in python-mode. When I hit backspace it deletes individual spaces, not 4 at a time as it should be.

What confuses me is that if I do `M-x py-electric-backspace`, it performs the command correctly and tells me I could have invoked the command by using backspace:

```
You can run the command `py-electric-backspace' with <backspace>
```

I'm using python-mode.el version 6.0.10, and I've tried reducing my .emacs file to only the few lines required to load python-mode.el.

I'd like backspace to work properly in python-mode, but I don't even know where to start figuring out what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**:

I've added the following to my .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
     (lambda () (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "DEL") 'py-electric-backspace)))
```

which seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the output of `C-h k <backspace>`?  My guess is that you are running in a terminal and you can't actually type `<backspace>`, since it gets changed by the terminal to `DEL`.  Running in a GUI, or binding `py-electric-backspace` to `DEL` should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I think this might be a bug in the latest python-mode.el (I've reported it here https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1027100) but this works in the meantime.